# ReactiveUI - Invoke delegate in view on view model property change

Tags: reactiveui

I'm just getting started with ReactiveUI and working on a small WPF drawing app. The drawing library I'm using (SkiaSharp) doesn't support binding an image to the XAML element, instead you invoke the InvalidateVisual method of the XAML element which fires a PaintSurface event that you respond to in order to draw the image.

So what I'm trying to do is observe a property of the view model and when the property changes invoke the InvalidateVisual method.

I've attempted to WhenAnyValue to observe a property of the view model and Do to invoke the InvalidateVisual method by setting up a subscription in the view's constructor thusly

```
this.WhenActivated(disposable =>
   {
      … // property bindings

      this.WhenAnyValue(x => ViewModel.SomeProperty)
         .Do(x => DrawingSpace.InvalidateVisual())
         .Subscribe()
         .DisposeWith(disposable);
   });
```

However this throws a System.NotSupportedException Unsupported expression type 'Constant'

What's the correct way to setup a subscription in a view that observes a view model property and invokes a delegate when the property changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is your issue:

```cs
this.WhenAnyValue(x => ViewModel.SomeProperty)
```

The WhenAnyValue needs a expression based on the `x` value passed in.

So in this case the correct approach would be to

```cs
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.ViewModel.SomeProperty)
```

Comment: also you could just do `Subscribe(propertyValue => { do stuff with property })` rather than using the `Do` operator.

Comment: Thanks, works just fine now. And I appreciate the Subscribe tip as well